# Image in Android Application

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android app in which I could store information at various points in a .jpg image and when I click at specific coordinate I could get that information. What I'm trying is something like this http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/US_Airways/US_Airways_Airbus_A320.php here if you go to particular seat you could get its information. I want to do this in android. Can anyone help me with this. How can I do this or is there any links to proceed. Thanks in advance.

[image: plane image]

Comment: I think this question is too general to provide specific help, but anyways, I can give you a hint: You have to think of a canvas and the placement of objects, that will be painted on the canvas (or remain invisible) and store their coordinates and various other information, that you need.

Comment: So the user can interact with your canvas (therefore you perform a hit detection and further actions (e.g. check if the user touched an area where a seat is placed and if this is the case, open a dialog to reserve the seat or something, just an example). I hope this helped a little, if you have more specific questions ask them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options for this:

First; you can write a custom view that draws a plane with seats, click events like `seatSelected`, `seatUnSelected` are handled inside this view and can be used with a callback outside of this class. ([Before starting to code, you have to read custom views, and try something easier for start;)](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html))

Second, you can create something like this, with android's default layouts and views. For example a `TableLayout` may be your main layout with the plane image as its background. This `TableLayout` is going to have rows and those rows are going to have seats as `ImageView`s. All `ImageView`s will handle click events and you should use that events.

Second options is easier to implement.